Dyamically Update Column in Python DataFrame using substrings
Lets say I have a data frame lets call it A



Key_Word
Code




Market
A1


Theater
A2



And I have another Data Frame lets call it B



Sentence
Components_from_A




John went to the theater



Mary went to the Market and then the theater




I would like to find a way to dynamically update dataframe B such that it loops through each b.sentence, and record the A.Code if it finds an instance of the A.Key_word.If a keyword appears more than once in A, I would like it to appear only once in B.Components_from_A. If multiple keywords appear I would like it to be recorded as Code1+Code2+Code3.....



Sentence
Components_from_A




John went to the theater
A2


Mary went to the Market and then the theater
A1+A2


Jack decided to go to the theater now as opposed to going to the theater later
A2



I assume that I could build off something like
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    A=pd.read_csv('A.csv')
    B=pd.read_csv('B.csv')
    Dict=dict(zip(A.Key_Word,A.Code))


What I'm struggling with would be dynamically updating the column in B and the logic I would need to do it in the way I described

You can craft a regex, extractall the keywords, merge to get the matching Codes, finally drop_duplicates to only keep unique codes per row and groupby.agg to merge the codes in a single string:
import re

# make the comparison case insensitive
A['Key_Word'] = A['Key_Word'].str.casefold()

# craft a regex
pattern = '(%s)' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, A['Key_Word']))
# '(Market|Theater)'

# extract keywords, match the codes, aggregate, assign to A
B['Components_from_A'] = (B['Sentence']
 .str.casefold().str.extractall(pattern) # case insensitive extraction
 .droplevel('match').reset_index(0)      # keep index
 .merge(A, left_on=0, right_on='Key_Word') # match codes
 .drop_duplicates(['index', 'Code'])       # keep unique codes per row
 .groupby('index')['Code'].agg('+'.join)   # aggregate as single string
)

Output:
                                            Sentence Components_from_A
0                           John went to the theater                A2
1       Mary went to the Market and then the theater             A1+A2
2  Jack decided to go to the theater now as oppos...                A2


Thank you. Saved me hours of tedious labor

You can do this by creating a dictionary of the dataframe A and iterate through each sentence of B. Check if the are keywords of importance and collect the information
import pandas as pd

data_A = {'Key_Word': ['Market', 'Theater'], 'Code': ['A1', 'A2']}
data_B = {'Sentence': [
    'John went to the theater',
    'Mary went to the Market and then the theater',
    'Jack decided to go to the theater now as opposed to going to the theater later'
]}

A = pd.DataFrame(data_A)
B = pd.DataFrame(data_B)

keyword_to_code = dict(zip(A.Key_Word, A.Code))

def update_components(sentence, keyword_to_code):
    codes = set()  
    for keyword, code in keyword_to_code.items():
        if keyword.lower() in sentence.lower():
            codes.add(code)
    return '+'.join(sorted(codes))

B['Components_from_A'] = B['Sentence'].apply(lambda x: update_components(x, keyword_to_code))

print(B)


which gives you
                                            Sentence Components_from_A
0                           John went to the theater                A2
1       Mary went to the Market and then the theater             A1+A2
2  Jack decided to go to the theater now as oppos...                A2

